# JSON Normalize On Extremely Nested JSON Data Structure

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following JSON data structure.  I am trying to get it into a Pandas DataFrame.

The pandas.io.json json_normalize works OK, except for the 'tunnels-in' and 'tunnels-out' sections.  These are lists with some nested dictionaries inside of them.  I have tried almost every format of the json_normalize examples I have seen, without success.  About all I can get working is the following.

json_normalize(json_dict['data']['viptela-oper-vpn']['dpi']['flows'])

As soon as I add the variables to define additional structure, I just can't get past the errors.  I looked into alternative ways to do this - documented here - which do seem to work, but it doesn't seem to deal with any concept of vertical structure.  Here, we have a list of flows - and i want to flatten each flow out into separate columns - where each flow's value is in a different row of the same column

https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10

Does anyone know of a way to use the normalize function, while preserving the nested list of dictionaries?  And as you can see, not every flow has the tunnels-in/tunnels-out.  That was another complicating factor to my trying to flatten it out myself.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much,

**Data Structure**

```
{
  "data": {
    "viptela-oper-vpn": {
      "dpi": {
        "flows": [
          {
            "vpn-id": 1,
            "src-ip": "1.1.0.200",
            "dst-ip": "1.3.0.200",
            "src-port": 65369,
            "dst-port": 1967,
            "proto": "udp",
            "application": "udp",
            "family": "Network Service",
            "active-since": "2018-02-28T22:51:54+00:00",
            "packets": 2,
            "octets": 132,
            "tunnels-in": [
              {
                "index_me": 1,
                "local-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.104",
                  "color": "private2",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "remote-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.103",
                  "color": "private2",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "packets": 1,
                "octets": 80,
                "start-time": "2018-02-28T22:51:54+00:00"
              }
            ],
            "tunnels-out": [
              {
                "index_me": 1,
                "local-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.104",
                  "color": "private2",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "remote-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.103",
                  "color": "mpls",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "packets": 1,
                "octets": 52,
                "start-time": "2018-02-28T22:51:54+00:00"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "vpn-id": 1,
            "src-ip": "1.1.0.200",
            "dst-ip": "1.3.0.200",
            "src-port": 65529,
            "dst-port": 1967,
            "proto": "udp",
            "application": "udp",
            "family": "Network Service",
            "active-since": "2018-02-28T22:52:03+00:00",
            "packets": 2,
            "octets": 132,
            "tunnels-in": [
              {
                "index_me": 1,
                "local-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.104",
                  "color": "private2",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "remote-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.103",
                  "color": "private2",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "packets": 1,
                "octets": 80,
                "start-time": "2018-02-28T22:52:03+00:00"
              }
            ],
            "tunnels-out": [
              {
                "index_me": 1,
                "local-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.104",
                  "color": "private2",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "remote-tloc": {
                  "ip": "1.1.1.103",
                  "color": "mpls",
                  "encap": "ipsec"
                },
                "packets": 1,
                "octets": 52,
                "start-time": "2018-02-28T22:52:03+00:00"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "vpn-id": 512,
            "src-ip": "69.26.45.133",
            "dst-ip": "198.19.200.2",
            "src-port": 11895,
            "dst-port": 22,
            "proto": "tcp",
            "application": "ssh",
            "family": "Encrypted",
            "active-since": "2018-02-28T22:42:15+00:00",
            "packets": 1498,
            "octets": 797954
          },
          {
            "vpn-id": 512,
            "src-ip": "198.19.200.2",
            "dst-ip": "69.26.45.139",
            "src-port": 514,
            "dst-port": 514,
            "proto": "udp",
            "application": "syslog",
            "family": "Application Service",
            "active-since": "2018-02-28T22:50:59+00:00",
            "packets": 8,
            "octets": 2820
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Function So Far**

```
def myprint(file):
    file_var = ''
    with open(file) as f:
        file_var = f.read()
    extract_json_dict = re.compile('(\\n{\\n)(.*)(\\n}\\n)', re.DOTALL)
    json_string = extract_json_dict.search(file_var).group(0)
    json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
    df = json_normalize(json_dict['data']['viptela-oper-vpn']['dpi']['flows'])
```

**Columns That Show Up Now**

['active-since', 'application', 'dst-ip', 'dst-port', 'family', 'octets',
'packets', 'proto', 'src-ip', 'src-port', 'tunnels-in', 'tunnels-out',
'vpn-id']

**Columns I'd Like To Add In Addition To The Ones Displayed Above**

In essence, 'flattening' those two columns that have lists as values into additional columns, and have each flow's values in a unique row.

['tunnels-in_index_me',
'tunnels-in_remote-tloc_ip',
'tunnels-in_remote-tloc_color',
'tunnels-in_remote-tloc_encap',
'tunnels-out_remote-tloc_ip']

**Update 3/8/2018**

This seems to do what i want, for the columns that have lists of dictionaries in them.  But it needs the [0] identifier for the flow number.  Not sure if anyone knows of a way to get this to work for all flows - not one at a time.  If that can be done, i should be able to concatenate or merge based on the index number.  It would be even better to do the whole thing with a single json_normalize line - but beyond the issue with the [0], that seems to also have the added problem that not all flow numbers have the nested list of dictionaries.  i'll keep trying with this one, but any thoughts are appreciated.

```
json_normalize(json_dict['data']['viptela-oper-vpn']['dpi']['flows'][0]['tunnels-in'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with this right now. I got around that selection by index `[0]` issue by pulling it out into another pandas.dataframe. As such:

```
df = json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(list(json_dict['data']['viptela-oper-vpn']['dpi']['flows']))['tunnels-in'])
```